# can't read from file, Java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

When I try to run the programm, it always throws a FileNotFoundException, although the file exists in the same folder as the project. I tested it with the canRead() method and it returned false, but I can't figure out why it can't read from the file.

```
package sumOfFloats;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfFloats {


public static float sumFloats() throws FileNotFoundException{

    File file = new File("floatNumbers.txt");
    float[] array = new float[100];
    int i = 0 ;
    float floatSum = 0.0f;
    Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(file);

    while(fileReader.hasNextLine()){
        array[i] = fileReader.nextFloat();
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
        floatSum += array[i];
        i++;
    }

    return floatSum;
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.out.println(sumFloats());

}
}
```

Comment: Because your assumption (that the file is in the correct place) is invalid.

Comment: Where is the file `floatNumbers.txt` located? is it in your working directory?

Comment: Have you tried saving the .java file on your desktop, compiling it via the command-line, copying+pasting your .txt file on the desktop, and then running?

Comment: Verify your current folder by using `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: already did, as I said, the file is in the right directory, I tested it with getProperty, tried giving the absolute path, but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem could be caused by :

**Permission limit**

Check that you execute your program with valid permission (try to test with execute as administrator if you are in Windows , or root if you are in Unix)

**Relative path problem**

it's possible that you didn't set the valid path to your file, try to test with an absolute path to insure that you can read from it.

Answer (score 0):

As the package name is `sumOfFloats` i have assumed that you have a folder by the `sumOfFloats` in which your `class file` resides just place the `floatNumbers.txt` in that folder and try to recompile it and then execute the class

Comment: try reading like this InputStream stream =getClass().getResourceAsStream("floatNumbers.txt");
Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(stream);